Selecting feature and install location in Wix
I am creating a windows MSI installer using Wix (via HeatWave in visual studio). Currently I am using the WixUI_FeatureTree, to allow different components to be selected. This all works fine, however the browse button on the feature selection page is greyed out, and there is no dialog to select install location.
<UI Id="UI">
    <ui:WixUI Id="WixUI_FeatureTree" />
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />
</UI>

I can use the WixUI_InstallDir, but then I have no option to choose features.
<UI Id="UI">
    <ui:WixUI Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />
</UI>

I have found documentation on Wix very limited, and most of it still refers to v3. What I have found mentions creating a custom UI Dialog, which seems excessive to me. Is there no way to combine Feature Tree and Install Directory to get both sets of features (I don't even need the option to set feature install location separately, everything in the same directory is fine).
